# limit to infinity of Left Riemann Sum MATLAB

Tags: matlab, limit, infinity, riemann

Lets say I have created a function Sn=LeftRiemannSum(f,left,right,N) ,that computes the left riemann sum over the interval left to right with N subdomains.i.e.:

Sn=sum(f(xi)*h) for all subdomains i=0 to N-1. f is my function and xi=left+i*h , so the input arguments left=x0 and right=xN.

Let f be my anonymous function (ex f=@(x)(x.*log(1+x)) .

I also estimated the Sn for varying N, from N=10 to 100000.

Now, I simply want to compute the value of the series Sn when N -> infinity. Inside the function I have a for loop [ for i=0:(N-1)] so I will have endless loop ..

Can I pass the function somehow to the 'limit' command? Any clues?

Thanx!

PS: The main part of the code of my function LeftRiemann Sum is the following:

```
for i=0:(N-1)
    x=x0+i.*h;
    y=f(x);
    A=y.*h;
    S=S+A
  end
   Sn=S
```

Comment: What happens if you check `doc limit` and start at one of those examples, in an attempt to work up to your actual function?

Comment: Could you please clarify if your question is related to the usage of the Symbolic Math Toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

If `N -> inf` the value of the Riemann sum will be the integral of the function in the interval [left, right].

One can introduce a check like this:

```
function Sn = LeftRiemannSum(f, left, right, N)

if isinf(N)
    Sn = exact integral of the function f in the interval [left, right]
    return
end

% // Rest of the code
```

the challenge here is to calculate the analytic integral of `f`. Unless you use the symbolic math toolbox, all the results from Matlab algorithms will be approximations.

Since you cannot really run your loop til infinity, I see two options:

1. I would declare a limit for `N` and throw an error if the input is greater than the limit.
2. Internaly define infinity as a high number, whenever you receive `inf` as parameter, you replace it by, let's say, N=1e200. Take into account that with this strategy your algorithm could take a long time to finish executing.

Comment: The asker asks about how to use the `limit` command which is part of the symbolic toolbox. As such I think a (somewhat vague) answer of how to deal with this if you don't have that toolbox is a bit out of place.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I do not think the OP is referring to the symbolic math toolbox, since it is not mentioned in the question. Only the OP can clarify that point. For a symbolic system, passing `N=inf` would pose no problem.